# Typescript interfaces : How to anything other than the known key has to be <T>?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to have an interface where anything other than the known props has to be a specific type.

Example:

```js
interface ITest {
    prop1: string;
    prop2?: number;
    [key: string]: IAnotherInterface | AnotherType // Everthing else that is not "prop1" or "prop2"
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The was I would go about this is by making a base interface and extending it then use the [Omit](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk) type.

**Example:**

```js
interface BaseInterface {
  [key: string]: SomeType
}

type OmittedKeys = "key1" | "key2"

interface Extended extends Omit<BaseInterface, OmittedKeys> {
  key1: string,
  key2: number
}
```

Comment: I tested this just now but it does not work. Thanks for answering though...

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is only possible with [Negated Types](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29317) which is still an open issue at the time of this writing. The only sane way to approach this for now is to use a union type along with another interface:

```js
interface IBase {
    "!prop1": string;
}

interface ITest extends IBase {
    [key: string]: string | typeA | InterfaceB // etc... 
}
```

And than later in the code reference the more strict type as needed:

```js
function fn(arg: ITest): IBase | ITest {
    if (arg["!prop1"]) {
        return arg as IBase
    } else {
        return arg as ITest
    }
}
```